# how to click button in c# webview

Tags: c#, webview

I'm working on trying to write an c# program that will click a button on a webpage automatically. I know I could use a chrome driver, but I don't want this to turn into a browser and version specific application.

This is what I came up with so far, but I'm having some difficulty determining how to be able to trigger that button to be clicked once I have found the correct button.

```
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    var func = string.Format(@"document.getElementsByClassName('size-grid-button').innerText = '{0}';", size);            
    await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { func });
```

**EDIT**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18801824/10496382) is what I'm basing my project off currently, but I can't find a button based on innerText and then simulate button click.

Comment: Webview2 is the latest control. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Comment: @user9938 I have followed the WebView2, but this still doesn't answer how I can find an element based on the innerText and then trigger the button to be clicked.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete code example using NuGet package **Microsoft.Web.WebView2** (v. 1.0.721-prerelease). See the Webview2 Release Notes for requirements.

**Resources**:

- [Introduction to Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)
- [WebView2 Release
  Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/releasenotes)
- [Microsoft Edge Insider Channels](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/)
- [Microsoft Edge for
  Business](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download)

**Note**: This example will be using WinForms--Windows Forms App (.NET Framework). When using .NET Framework, versions >= 4.6.2 are supported (previously version 4.6.2 or greater was required. However, if one looks at the NuGet package folders, it appears that the required minimum version may now be 4.5. See the release notes for more information). See the documentation for other supported SDKs.

Visual Studio versions 2017 and 2019 are supported. If you don't have either, you may be able to [Download Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) -- which is free.

**Download and install Microsoft Edge Dev** (aka "Dev Channel"): [Microsoft Edge Insider Channels](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/) -- see documentation for other options.

**Open Visual Studio** - (2017 or 2019)

Set **Default package management format** to **PackageReference** (this is optional, but recommended). See [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) for more information.

**2019**:

- Click **Continue without code**
- In Visual Studio (VS) menu, click
  **Tools**
- Select **Options**
- Expand **NuGet Package Manager**
- Click **General**
- Under **Package Management**, set `Default package management format:` to `PackageReference`

**2017**:

- In Visual Studio (VS) menu, click
  **Tools**
- Select **Options**
- Expand **NuGet Package Manager**
- Click **General**
- Under **Package Management**, set `Default package management format:` to `PackageReference`

**Create New Project**

**2019**:

- In VS menu, click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- Optional: Use the following options to limit displayed selections: C#
  Windows Desktop
- Click **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**
- Click **Next**
- Enter a name for you project (ex: WebView2Test), select desired location, and set Framework to a version >= 4.6.2
- Click **Create**

**2017**:

- In VS menu, click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- Expand **Visual C#**
- Click **Windows Desktop**
- Click **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**
- Enter a name for you project (ex: WebView2Test), select desired location, and set Framework to a version >= 4.6.2
- Click **OK**

Add **Microsoft.Web.WebView2** NuGet package to project (2019/2017)

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**
- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>
- Select **Manage NuGet
  Packages...**
- Click **Browse**
- Check **Include prerelease**
- Search: **Microsoft.Web.WebView2**
- Select Version **1.0.721-prerelease**
- Set any desired options by clicking the down-arrow next to the left of
  "Options" to show the available options (ie: Install and Update options
  and Uninstall options)
- Click **Install**
- If a window pops up, click **OK**

**Optional**: Add MenuStrip to Form (Form1)

- In Solution Explorer, click **Form1.cs** to select it
- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Expand **All Windows Forms**
- Select **MenuStrip**
- Click on Form (Form1) to add the control to the Form

**Optional**: Add StatusStrip to Form (Form1)

- In Solution Explorer, click **Form1.cs** to select it
- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Expand **All Windows Forms**
- Select **StatusStrip**
- Click on Form (Form1) to add the control to the Form

**Add SplitContainer to Form** (Form1)

- In Solution Explorer, click **Form1.cs** to select it
- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Expand **All Windows Forms**
- Select **SplitContainer**
- Click on Form (Form1) to add the control to the Form

**Add button to left panel of SplitContainer (splitContainer1)**

- In Solution Explorer, click **Form1.cs** to select it
- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Expand **All Windows Forms**
- Select **Button**
- Click on Form (Form1) to add the control to the Form. If necessary, move the button to the left panel (panel1) of the SplitContainer.

**Change button properties**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Properties Window**
- In Properties Window, use the drop-down to select the button (button1)
- Change (Name) to the desired name (ex: btnClickJSButton)
- Change text to desired text (ex: Click JS Button)

**Add WebView2 control to SplitContainer (panel2)**

- In Solution Explorer, click **Form1.cs** to select it
- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Expand **WebView2 Windows Forms Control**

**Note**: If "WebView2 Windows Forms Control" isn't in the Toolbox, right-click in an open space in the Toolbox, and select "Choose Items". Then click "Browse". Go to  %UserProfile%.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webview2\1.0.721-prerelease\lib\net45 (ex: C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webview2\1.0.721-prerelease\lib\net45). Choose "Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll"

- Select **WebView2**
- Click on Form (Form1) to add the control to the Form. If necessary, move the WebView2 control to the right panel (panel2) of the SplitContainer.

**Change WebView2 properties**

- In Properties Window, use the drop-down to select the WebView2 control instance (webView21)
- Set **Dock** property to **Fill**

**Add Load event handler to Form** (Form1)

- In Solution Explorer, click **Form1.cs** to select it
- Double-click the top of the Form, which will add the event handler: Form1_Load

**Add Button click event handler**

- In Solution Explorer, click **Form1.cs** to select it
- On the Form (Form1), double-click the button (btnClickJSButton), to create the click event handler (btnClickJSButton_Click)

**Create a folder for HTML code**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Folder**. The folder will be selected. If not, right-click the folder and select "Rename". Set the name to "HTML".

**Create index.html**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>
- Right-click **HTML** folder
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Item**
- Click **HTML Page** (Name: index.html)
- Click **Add**

**Change index.html property**

- In Solution Explorer, click **index.html** to select it
- In Properties Window, set **Build Action** to **Embedded Resource**

**Add code to**: index.html

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script>
        function btnClickAction(name) {
            alert('button ' + name + ' was clicked');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="button" class="size-grid-button" id="size-grid-button1" onclick="btnClickAction('size-grid-button1')">Click Me 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="size-grid-button" id="size-grid-button2" onclick="btnClickAction('size-grid-button2')">Click Me 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="size-grid-button" id="size-grid-button3" onclick="btnClickAction('size-grid-button3')" value="Click Me 3">Click Me 3</button>

    <input type="button" class="size-grid-button" id="size-grid-button4" onclick="btnClickAction('size-grid-button4')" value="Click Me 4" />

</body>
</html>
```

**Create a folder for JavaScript code**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Folder**. The folder will be selected. If not, right-click the folder and select "Rename". Set the name to "JavaScript".

**Create TestButtonClick.js**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>
- Right-click **JavaScript** folder
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Item**
- Click **JavaScript File** (Name: TestButtonClick.js)
- Click **Add**

**Change TestButtonClick.js property**

- In Solution Explorer, click **TestButtonClick.js** to select it
- In Properties Window, set **Build Action** to **Embedded Resource**

**Option 1** (desired HTML element is 'button')

Example:

```
<button type="button" class="size-grid-button" id="size-grid-button1" onclick="btnClickAction('size-grid-button1')">Click Me 1</button>
```

**Add code to**: TestButtonClick.js

**TestButtonClick.js** (Option 1)

```
function clickDesiredButtonByInnerText(btnInnerText) {

    //let buttons = document.getElementByTagName('button');
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    let i = 0;
    let result = null;

    if (buttons) {
        
        for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            //window.chrome.webview.postMessage("button[" + i + "].innerText: " + buttons[i].innerText);

            if (buttons[i].innerText === btnInnerText) {
                buttons[i].click();
                result = btnInnerText + ' clicked';
                break; //exit loop
            }
        }
    }

    //window.chrome.webview.postMessage("result:" + result);
    return result;
}
```

**Option 2** (desired HTML element is 'input')

Example:

```
<input type="button" class="size-grid-button" id="size-grid-button4" onclick="btnClickAction('size-grid-button4')" value="Click Me 4" />
```

**Add code to**: TestButtonClick.js

**TestButtonClick.js** (Option 2)

```
function clickDesiredInputButtonByTextValue(btnValue) {

    let i = 0;
    let result = null;

    buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input');

    if (buttons) {

        for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            //window.chrome.webview.postMessage("button[" + i + "].value: " + buttons[i].value + ' type: ' + buttons[i].type);

            if (buttons[i].type === 'button' && buttons[i].value === btnValue) {
                buttons[i].click();
                result = btnValue + ' clicked';
                break; //exit loop
            }
        }
    }

    //window.chrome.webview.postMessage("result:" + result);
    return result;
}
```

**Option 3** (desired HTML element is ('button' OR 'input') AND element has an 'id' attribute that has a unique value)

**Add code to**: TestButtonClick.js

**TestButtonClick.js** (Option 3)

```
function clickDesiredButtonById(btnId) {
    let result = null;
    let desiredButton = document.getElementById(btnId);

    if (desiredButton) {
        desiredButton.click();
        result = 'button with id = ' + btnId + ' clicked';
    }

    //window.chrome.webview.postMessage("result:" + result);
    return result;
}
```

**Create a new class** (HelperLoadResource.cs)

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>
- Select **Add**
- Select **Class...** (Name: HelperLoadResource.cs)

**Add using statements** (HelperLoadResource.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

**Add code to**: HelperLoadResource.cs

**Note**: `HelperLoadResource.ReadResource` will read text from the embedded files (HTML and JavaScript) and put the text into a string variable.

**HelperLoadResource.cs**

```
public static class HelperLoadResource
{
    public static string ReadResource(string filename)
    {
        //use UTF8 encoding as the default encoding
        return ReadResource(filename, Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public static string ReadResource(string filename, Encoding fileEncoding)
    {
        string fqResourceName = string.Empty;
        string result = string.Empty;

        //get executing assembly
        Assembly execAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        //get resource names
        string[] resourceNames = execAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        if (resourceNames != null && resourceNames.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string rName in resourceNames)
            {
                if (rName.EndsWith(filename))
                {

                    //set value to 1st match
                    //if the same filename exists in different folders,
                    //the filename can be specified as <folder name>.<filename>
                    //or <namespace>.<folder name>.<filename>
                    fqResourceName = rName;

                    //exit loop
                    break;
                }
            }

            //if not found, throw exception
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fqResourceName))
            {
                throw new Exception($"Resource '{filename}' not found.");
            }

            //get file text
            using (Stream s = execAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fqResourceName))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s, fileEncoding))
                {
                    //get text
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

**Add code to**: Form1.cs

- In Solution Explorer, click <project name>
- Right-click **Form1.cs**
- Select **View Code**

**Add using statements** (Form1.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

**Add method `InitializeCoreWebView2Async`** (Form1.cs)

**InitializeCoreWebView2Async** (Form1.cs)

```
private async Task InitializeCoreWebView2Async()
{
    //initialize CorewWebView2
    await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
}
```

**Add code to**: `Form1_Load` (Form1.cs)

**Note**: Add the `async` keyword to `Form_Load`.

**Form1_Load** (Form1.cs)

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //show MS Edge version -- also ensures that an exception will be raised if proper MS Edge version isn't installed
    Debug.WriteLine(CoreWebView2Environment.GetAvailableBrowserVersionString());

    //initialized CorewWebView2
    await InitializeCoreWebView2Async();

    //get HTML
    string html = HelperLoadResource.ReadResource("index.html");
    
    //display HTML in WebView2
    webView21.NavigateToString(html);
    
}
```

**Subscribe to WebView2 `CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted` event**

- In Properties Window, use the drop-down to select the WebView2 instance (webView21)
- Click the orange lightning bolt to see available events
- Double-click **CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted** to add the event handler to the Form (Form1.cs)

**Add the following code to CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted**

**CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted** (Form1.cs)

```
private void webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e) 
{

    //subscribe to CoreWebView2 events (add event handlers)
    webView21.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += CoreWebView2_WebMessageReceived;         
}
```

**CoreWebView2_WebMessageReceived** (Form1.cs)

```
private void CoreWebView2_WebMessageReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Info: MSG (JSON): " + e.WebMessageAsJson);
    Debug.WriteLine("Info: MSG (String): " + e.TryGetWebMessageAsString());
}
```

**If using Option 1 above (desired HTML element is 'button'), add method `ClickWebView2ButtonByInnerText`**

**ClickWebView2ButtonByInnerText** (Form1.cs)

```
private async Task ClickWebView2ButtonByInnerText(string btnInnerText)
{
    if (webView21 != null && webView21.CoreWebView2 != null)
    {
        string jsCode = HelperLoadResource.ReadResource("TestButtonClick.js");
        jsCode += System.Environment.NewLine;
        jsCode += "clickDesiredButtonByInnerText('" + btnInnerText + "');";

        var result = await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsCode);

        Debug.WriteLine("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

**Add the following code to the Button click event handler `btnClickButton_Click`**  (Option 1)

**Note**: Add the `async` keyword.

```
private async void btnClickButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ClickWebView2ButtonByInnerText("Click Me 3");
}
```

**If using Option 2 above (desired HTML element is 'input'), add method `ClickWebView2InputButton`**

**ClickWebView2InputButton** (Form1.cs)

```
private async Task ClickWebView2InputButton(string btnValue)
{
    if (webView21 != null && webView21.CoreWebView2 != null)
    {
        string jsCode = HelperLoadResource.ReadResource("TestButtonClick.js");
        jsCode += System.Environment.NewLine;
        jsCode += "clickDesiredInputButtonByTextValue('" + btnValue + "');";

        var result = await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsCode);

        Debug.WriteLine("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

**Add the following code to the Button click event handler `btnClickButton_Click`**  (Option 2)

**Note**: Add the `async` keyword.

```
private async void btnClickButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await ClickWebView2InputButton("Click Me 4");
}
```

**If using Option 3 above (desired HTML element is ('button' OR 'input') AND element has an 'id' attribute that has a unique value), add method `ClickWebView2ButtonById`**

**ClickWebView2ButtonById** (Form1.cs)

```
private async Task ClickWebView2ButtonById(string btnId)
{
    if (webView21 != null && webView21.CoreWebView2 != null)
    {
        string jsCode = HelperLoadResource.ReadResource("TestButtonClick.js");
        jsCode += System.Environment.NewLine;
        jsCode += "clickDesiredButtonById('" + btnId + "');";

        var result = await webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsCode);

        Debug.WriteLine("result: " + result);
    }
}
```

**Add the following code to the Button click event handler `btnClickButton_Click`**  (Option 3)

**Note**: Add the `async` keyword.

```
private async void btnClickButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     await ClickWebView2ButtonById("size-grid-button2");
     await ClickWebView2ButtonById("size-grid-button4");
}
```

Run the program.
Click the button on the form to test.

**Additional Resources**

- [Download Visual Studio SDKs](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks)
- [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)